# "eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented" when running android apps on android studio emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio

this is my first post.

I've recently downloaded Android Studio and seem to be having some trouble with the emulator. Every time I run an application (even if I try to run the initial HelloWorld application right after the "create new project" wizard). I get the following error message in the logcat:

10-08 11:36:53.600      850-850/app.helloagain W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

It seems to work fine in the emulator, but this blue text appears in the logcat and I would like to understand what is going on, if it is a problem, and if so, how can I fix it.

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Mike

Comment: Extended discussion in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966496/android-studio-emulator-eglsurfaceattrib-not-implemented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for those that have a similar problem I thought I should post my eventual solution. Unfortunately after trying just about everything I ended up performing a full Windows re-install. I have no idea what the problem was but that solved it. So don't give up here newbies!