# Android Studio - Emulator - eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have created an application with android studio, never change a single word in any file.

when trying to run it on the emulator I got the following error:

```
W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6c1ace0,error=EGL_SUCCESS
I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6c1ace0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

I am not getting the same problem when I run it on a real device:

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/art﹕ Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.internal.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
```

Comment: when you unticked the Use Host GPU, could you write to files?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I've found the same thing, but only on emulators that have the **Use Host GPU** setting ticked. Try turning that off, you'll no longer see those warnings (and the emulator will run horribly, horribly slowly..)

In my experience those warnings are harmless. Notice that the "error" is EGL_SUCCESS, which would seem to indicate no error at all!

Comment: It's in : Tools > Android > AVD Manager > Edit the virtual device and the Use Host GPU setting is found there.

Comment: Requires API > 15 ([JellyBean](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=suzunone) or better) when using x86 CPU/ABI.  So, for IceCreamSandwich and below, when emulating [mips CPU/ABI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13417534/what-is-android-mips-system-image), performance becomes acceptable.  (arm also too slow it seems.)

Comment: yes, but any method to solve this problem ? hardware accelerated / Looper ? please.

Comment: Tried with my physical device and worked, while it gives error on my emulator.

Comment: @LamonteCristo could help me to find out this option I'm using Nexus 5 API 22 x86 please find this image https://s14.postimg.org/62vlvbicx/scmain.png

Answer (score 1):

Fix: Unlock your device before running it.

Hi Guys: Think I may have a fix for this:

Sounds ridiculous but try unlocking your Virtual Device; i.e. use your mouse to swipe and open. Your app should then work!!

Comment: Why does this have more down than up-votes?

If you came here, like me, misinterpreting the warning as an error, and concluding that things weren't working – this is actually what you need to do, if you can live with the warning.

Comment: My virtual device is unlocked, and I'm still getting this warning.

Comment: This was the resolution to my simulator not automatically displaying the app as I expected. I had to manually "swipe" up to "unlock" the device.

Comment: Fixing the condition by unlocking the device via a 'swipe' first has also been reported in other SO threads. So, do not dismiss the suggestion, only because it does not apply to your case, or does not 'sound right'.