# Opengl error on default android app - eglSurfaceAttrib no implemented

Tags: android

Im a android newbie. Just installed android studio version 1.1.0 on ubuntu instalation.

When trying to compile the default helloworld app I get the following opengl errorson logcat:

> -03-17 08:03:01.137    1983-1999/com.example.david.helloandroid W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
>   -03-17 08:03:01.137    1983-1999/com.example.david.helloandroid W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface
>   0xa68175c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
>   -03-17 08:03:01.607    1983-1999/com.example.david.helloandroid W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
>   -03-17 08:03:01.607    1983-1999/com.example.david.helloandroid W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface
>   0xa68175c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS

The emulator is the default Nexus 5 API 21 X86 android 5.0

Comment: I am also having this issue... same version and same emulator. Am about to attempt an update... will post back here.

Comment: Extended discussion in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966496/android-studio-emulator-eglsurfaceattrib-not-implemented

Comment: Welcome to Android!  Big Red Errors are considered "normal" for us.  As long as the thing works, just ignore any errors that come around!  Don't worry, be happy!  And drink lots and lots of alcohol (or prozac if you're a teetotaler)!

Answer (score 1):

But app is started normal? If yes (because it's simple HelloWorld app), then you shouldn't worry about it, it's an emulator OpenGL workflow error, and (as usual) not cause any problems. 
You can try to use your GPU for OpenGL render for better performance (and as try to get rid from those logs), by selecting "Use Host GPU" within the setting, when creating your emulator.

You may use other emulator, like Genymotion, but (from my experience) it also have those log messages.

If you look more through Android emulator, or device logcat log, you may found, that many different services or apps logging about some errors, but it (usually) not affect user experience and application work.

Comment: I am also having the same problems, and it is definitely not an ignoreable error - there seems to be some type of buffer swap going on, and I see pieces of the Launcher and other graphics cut up, tiled, rotated all interspersed with my layouts...

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue, however I was using the Nexus S Emulator.  The problem for me seemed to be that I had not "Swiped to Unlock" the Nexus S screen before running the app.  After I unlocked the phone, the "Hello World!" app ran properly.  I hope this helps!