# Android Emulator eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm newbie with android studio and his emulator.
I'm making my first app but when I load the emulator, the app is empty and I received some errors in logcat

```
03-26 19:48:24.399    2310-2325/com.example.myhelloworld2 W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-26 19:48:24.399    2310-2325/com.example.myhelloworld2 W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6c2e0c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#8f07d3">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:src="@drawable/homeclosetome"
    android:layout_marginBottom="116dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:src="@drawable/iconclosetome"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:maxWidth="60dp"
    android:maxHeight="60dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_marginStart="34dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:onClick="closeToMe"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/iconnews"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:src="@drawable/iconemail"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Close To Me"
    android:id="@+id/closetome"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:onClick="closeToMe"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Applications"
    android:id="@+id/applications"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Contact us"
    android:id="@+id/contactus"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I do?

I'm using Android Studio on Mac 10.10.2 and Android 5.1 x86_64 Api level 22 as emulator
I read something about Genymotion but I don't want install VirtualBox.

Comment: Do you have video acceleration for the emulator?

Comment: I don't know...probably not. How can verify that?

Comment: Check out http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-graphics

Comment: I test the accelerator with kextstat | grep intel and this is the result

133    0 0xffffff7f82abb000 0x14000    0x14000 com.intel.kext.intelhaxm (1.1.1) <7 5 4 3 1>

I selected an emulator with x86 but the app is empty

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a dup of [Android Studio - Emulator - eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966496/android-studio-emulator-eglsurfaceattrib-not-implemented)

W/ <-- Is a warning see http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html

> The priority is one of the following character values, ordered from
>   lowest to highest priority: V — Verbose (lowest priority) D — Debug I
>   — Info W — Warning E — Error F — Fatal S — Silent (highest priority,
>   on which nothing is ever printed)

@Alessandro Zaccheroni - Have you tried to run your app on a physical device? Or can you provide a more detailed error log?

Comment: Indeed, this is a a duplicate question, so read the discussion on that thread. Even though this message is issued as a "Warning", it's the last one I get before the image load into the emulator stops.