# make HTTP request with genymotion emulator android

Tags: android, httprequest, getjson, genymotion

I want to make a HTTPRequest with genymotion emulator. (having no physical device...).
but I am getting an error :

```
 W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 262K, 16% free 4387K/5216K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 12ms
W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: No value for success
```

and the HTTP request failed.

connection to server and calling the request:

```
    CallServer getGender = new CallServer();
    getGender.execute();
```

this is my CallServer class:

```
public class CallServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    int success = 0;
    String urlAddress;
    String data;

        public CallServer()
        {
            data = null;
            urlAddress = "https://taub-prayer-ramym.c9.io/checkMode";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


            try {
                final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
                JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

                Log.i("LetsRun", "sending message to server...");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        urlAddress, "GET",null);

                if(json == null)
                {
                    return "Can't connect to server.";
                }

                data = json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (data == null){
                    return "ERROR!";
                }
                else{ // on success
                    System.out.print(data);
                    return data;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            super.onPostExecute(file_url);
        }

        public String getData() {
            return data;
        }

}
```

and this is my JSONParser class:

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // Construct the client and the HTTP request.
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            // Execute the POST request and store the response locally.
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            // Extract data from the response.
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            // Open an inputStream with the data content.
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            // Create a BufferedReader to parse through the inputStream.
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            // Declare a string builder to help with the parsing.
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            // Declare a string to store the JSON object data in string form.
            String line = null;

            // Build the string until null.
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            // Close the input stream.
            is.close();
            // Convert the string builder data to an actual string.
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // Try to parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // Return the JSON Object.
        return jObj;

    }


    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
//                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
//                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

I have tried the server requests on chrome and it works well... can someone try it on a hardware device? of, any suggestions for whats wrong ? thanks alot

edit:
full error:

```
D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
    08-26 06:40:17.424    1333-1339/com.example.atheel.prayer D/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
    08-26 06:40:17.512    1333-1333/com.example.atheel.prayer I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
    08-26 06:40:17.512    1333-1333/com.example.atheel.prayer W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 608: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
    08-26 06:40:17.532    1333-1333/com.example.atheel.prayer D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    08-26 06:40:17.556    1333-1333/com.example.atheel.prayer I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
    08-26 06:40:17.556    1333-1333/com.example.atheel.prayer W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 630: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
    08-26 06:40:17.560    1333-1333/com.example.atheel.prayer D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    08-26 06:40:17.592    1333-1345/com.example.atheel.prayer I/LetsRun﹕ sending message to server...
    08-26 06:40:17.656    1333-1336/com.example.atheel.prayer D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 196K, 16% free 4254K/5016K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 13ms
    08-26 06:40:17.700    1333-1333/com.example.atheel.prayer D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
    08-26 06:40:17.704    1333-1333/com.example.atheel.prayer D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8512dd8, tid 1333
    08-26 06:40:17.712    1333-1333/com.example.atheel.prayer D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
    08-26 06:40:17.712    1333-1333/com.example.atheel.prayer D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
    08-26 06:40:17.792    1333-1333/com.example.atheel.prayer W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    08-26 06:40:17.804    1333-1333/com.example.atheel.prayer D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
    08-26 06:40:17.868    1333-1336/com.example.atheel.prayer D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 269K, 17% free 4372K/5208K, paused 2ms+0ms, total 8ms
    08-26 06:40:18.208    1333-1345/com.example.atheel.prayer W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: No value for success
    08-26 06:40:18.208    1333-1345/com.example.atheel.prayer W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
    08-26 06:40:18.208    1333-1345/com.example.atheel.prayer W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:510)
    08-26 06:40:18.208    1333-1345/com.example.atheel.prayer W/System.err﹕ at com.example.atheel.prayer.CallServer.doInBackground(CallServer.java:79)
    08-26 06:40:18.212    1333-1345/com.example.atheel.prayer W/System.err﹕ at com.example.atheel.prayer.CallServer.doInBackground(CallServer.java:17)
    08-26 06:40:18.212    1333-1345/com.example.atheel.prayer W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    08-26 06:40:18.212    1333-1345/com.example.atheel.prayer W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    08-26 06:40:18.212    1333-1345/com.example.atheel.prayer W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    08-26 06:40:18.212    1333-1345/com.example.atheel.prayer W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    08-26 06:40:18.212    1333-1345/com.example.atheel.prayer W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    08-26 06:40:18.212    1333-1345/com.example.atheel.prayer W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    08-26 06:40:48.736    1333-1336/com.example.atheel.prayer D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 356K, 18% free 4400K/5324K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 4ms
```

Comment: a simple search will yield you results. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28975406/1061944

Comment: I have seen that, but coudnt find Use Host GPU on genymotion. thank you

Comment: Please post the complete error dump if you can.

Comment: can you send the json, or json url will be the best

Comment: I edited the url. thank you
urlAddress = "https://taub-prayer-ramym.c9.io/checkMode"

Comment: it shows Cannot GET /checkMode%22 i am not able to see anu json

Comment: https://taub-prayer-ramym.c9.io/checkMode

Comment: In the logs, it shows -- ***org.json.JSONException: No value for success*** -- would help if you could post a sample of the JSON response you're expecting to receive.