# Switch activities in Android Activities

Tags: java, android

Whenever I try to click on a button and switch activities, it always gives me the error and stays on the same activity without doing anything:

> W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
>
> W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6d42940, error=EGL_SUCCESS

I thought that it was something in my manifest file, but I can't find anything.  I've tried changing many things around and inserting different filters and such and nothing solves this problem.

My code is:

1. AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                package="com.example.robertmonks.mytestapp" >
        
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="Main_Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="Login_Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login_"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="Register_Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register_"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

2. Main_Activity

```java
package com.example.robertmonks.mytestapp;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.AlertDialog;

public class Main_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    android.widget.Button   logoutButton;
    android.widget.EditText password;
    android.widget.EditText username;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_login_);

        password = (android.widget.EditText) findViewById( R.id.etPassword );
        username = (android.widget.EditText) findViewById( R.id.etEmailAddress );
        logoutButton = (android.widget.Button) findViewById( R.id.blogin);

        logoutButton.setOnClickListener(new android.widget.Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.blogin) {
                    logoutButtonClicked();//move action to new method to keep code clean
                }
            }
        });

    }


    private void logoutButtonClicked()
    {
        android.content.Intent loginintent = new android.content.Intent(Main_Activity.this, Login_Activity.class);
        Main_Activity.this.startActivity(loginintent);
        android.util.Log.d("Logout", "Attempted");
    }

}
```

3. Login_Activity

```java
package com.example.robertmonks.mytestapp;
        
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.AlertDialog;

public class Login_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    android.widget.Button   loginButton;
    android.widget.Button   registerButton;
    android.widget.EditText password;
    android.widget.EditText username;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_login_);
        
        password = (android.widget.EditText) findViewById( R.id.etPassword );
        username = (android.widget.EditText) findViewById( R.id.etEmailAddress );
        loginButton = (android.widget.Button) findViewById( R.id.blogin);
        registerButton = (android.widget.Button) findViewById( R.id.bregister);
        
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new android.widget.Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(v.getId() == R.id.blogin) {
                    loginButtonClicked();//move action to new method to keep code clean
                }
                if(v.getId() == R.id.bregister) {
                    registerButtonClicked();
                }
            }
        });
        
        registerButton.setOnClickListener(new android.widget.Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(v.getId() == R.id.bregister) {
                    registerButtonClicked();
                }
            }
        });
        
    }
        
    private void loginButtonClicked()
    {
    
        //startActivity(Main_Activity.class);
        android.util.Log.d("Login", "Attempted");
    }
        
    private void registerButtonClicked()
    {
        android.content.Intent registerintent = new android.content.Intent(Login_Activity.this, Register_Activity.class);
        Login_Activity.this.startActivity(registerintent);
        android.util.Log.d("New User", "Attempted");
    }
    
}
```

4. Registration_Activity

```java
package com.example.robertmonks.mytestapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

public class Register_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


    android.widget.Button   createAccountButton;
    android.widget.Button   LoginPageButton;
    android.widget.EditText password1;
    android.widget.EditText password2;
    android.widget.EditText FirstName;
    android.widget.EditText LastName;
    android.widget.EditText EmailAddress;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_login_);
        
        password1 = (android.widget.EditText) findViewById( R.id.etFirstPassword );
        password2 = (android.widget.EditText) findViewById( R.id.etSecondPassword );
        FirstName = (android.widget.EditText) findViewById( R.id.etFirstName );
        LastName = (android.widget.EditText) findViewById( R.id.etLastName );
        createAccountButton = (android.widget.Button) findViewById( R.id.blogin);
        LoginPageButton = (android.widget.Button) findViewById( R.id.bregister);
        EmailAddress = (android.widget.EditText) findViewById( R.id.etEmailAddress);
        
        createAccountButton.setOnClickListener(new android.widget.Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(v.getId() == R.id.blogin) {
                    createAccountButtonClicked();//move action to new method to keep code clean
                }
            }
        });
        
        LoginPageButton.setOnClickListener(new android.widget.Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.bregister) {
                    LoginPageButtonClicked();
                }
            }
        });
        
    }
        
    private void createAccountButtonClicked()
    {
        android.util.Log.d("Create Account", "Attempted");
    }
    
    private void LoginPageButtonClicked()
    {
        android.util.Log.d("Login Page", "Attempted");
        android.content.Intent loginintent = new android.content.Intent(this, Login_Activity.class);
        startActivity(loginintent);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: the problem lies on click of which button?

Comment: Well it opens up the login page on startup, so whenever I click RegisterButtonClicked(), it invokes the method because it logs what I wanted it to, but it gives the error and remains on the same activity.

Answer (score 0):

For all the buttons, try changing the onclicklistener.
e.g. For the register button,

```
 registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
         }
     });
```

I hope this helps. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok... i think problem is your emulator configuration.
only on emulators that have the Use **Host GPU** setting ticked. Try turning that off, you'll no longer see those warnings (and the emulator will run horribly, horribly slowly..)
 **Tools > Android > AVD Manager > Edit the virtual device** and the Use Host GPU setting is found there.

for more detail.. [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966496/android-studio-emulator-eglsurfaceattrib-not-implemented)