# Android Studio error: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented/Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7f3f88dab6c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS

Tags: java, android

Every time I run my program, Android studio gives me these errors:

```
10-26 16:45:51.020 5758-5781/com.example.mm.myapplicationW/EGL_emulation:eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-26 16:45:51.020 5758-5781/com.example.mm.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7f3f88dab6c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

What is the reason for this? The program works on the emulator but I get these errors every time I click on a button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio - Emulator - eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966496/android-studio-emulator-eglsurfaceattrib-not-implemented)

Answer (score 1):

It might be emulator not having enough memory to load all of the startup data.

See
https://teamtreehouse.com/community/i-am-running-my-emulator-and-receiving-this-error-message

Answer (score 1):

1. Check for your functions writing upper and lower cases
2. Check for the scopes
3. If you have buttons check for its on click value