# android studio CoordinatorLayout & RecyclerView blank?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-cardview, android-coordinatorlayout

Runing my app i get a blank activity, for the time being i only have a list which should be projecting images, by reading these images addresses from JSON, and from the logcat i could see the the addresses being passed to the app, and logged, but not sure why the layout is not getting structured and i get a blank white screen.

Using Genymotion - android s6 - android studio 2.1.1

MyActivity;

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Collection;
  import java.util.HashMap;
  import java.util.Map;


  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> image_urls = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] android_image_urls = new String[image_urls.size()];


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    ImagesAddresses();
    initViews();

}
public void ImagesAddresses(){
    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/xxxxxx/xxx");
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            Map<String, String> allADR = (HashMap<String, String>) snapshot.getValue();
            if (allADR != null) {
                Collection<String> BlkADR = allADR.values();

                image_urls.addAll(BlkADR);
                android_image_urls = image_urls.toArray(android_image_urls);

                    Log.i("myTag", image_urls.toString());

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void initViews(){
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    ArrayList androidVersion = prepareData();
    DataAdapter adapter = new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(),androidVersion);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
private ArrayList prepareData(){

    ArrayList android_version = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<android_image_urls.length;i++){
        AndroidVersion androidVersion = new AndroidVersion();
        androidVersion.setAndroid_image_url(android_image_urls[i]);
        android_version.add(androidVersion);
    }
    return android_version;
}
 }
```

activity_main.xml;

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/card_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

DataAdapter.java;

```
  package net.janusjanus.interactive_layout;


 import android.content.Context;
 import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.ImageView;

 import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<AndroidVersion> android_version;
private Context context;

public DataAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<AndroidVersion> android_version) {
    this.context = context;
    this.android_version = android_version;

}

@Override
public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    Picasso.with(context).load(android_version.get(i).getAndroid_image_url()).resize(120, 60).into(viewHolder.img_android);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return android_version.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ImageView img_android;
    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        img_android = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img_android);
    }
}
}
```

AndroidVersion.java;

```
   package net.janusjanus.interactive_layout;


 public class AndroidVersion {

private String android_image_url;


public String getAndroid_image_url() {
    return android_image_url;
}

public void setAndroid_image_url(String android_image_url) {
    this.android_image_url = android_image_url;
}
}
```

going over the error i got the followin;

```
  05-15 04:19:57.942 7827-7875/net.janusjanus.interactive_layout I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
 05-15 04:19:58.055 7827-7875/net.janusjanus.interactive_layout W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
 05-15 04:19:58.056 7827-7875/net.janusjanus.interactive_layout W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe7d65fe0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
 05-15 04:20:01.188 7827-7827/net.janusjanus.interactive_layout I/myTag: [http://res.cloudinary.com/xxxxx/image/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/fw88v6xu6wybamg9zzt6.jpg, http://res.cloudinary.com/xxxx/image/upload/xxxxx/xxxxdgfddd.jpg, http://res.cloudinary.com/xxxxxxx/jjjjjj/upload/xxxxxxxx/vvvghgggggg.jpg]
```

DataAdapter.java;
and i have searched stackoverflow for eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

increased the emulator disk size, implemented Gapp and other instructions i found on the following posts;
[Android Studio - Emulator - eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966496/android-studio-emulator-eglsurfaceattrib-not-implemented)

but still no layout.

As the user below suggested, i changed the initialization of initView, into the end of ImageAddresses, in order for it to follow the step of retrieving the addresses, and also logged the android_version.size(); which returns zero, thus the layout is still blank but not sure how to fix this problem,

Logcat after changes ;

```
   05-15 05:59:25.025 3473-3537/net.janusjanus.interactive_layout I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
  05-15 05:59:25.174 3473-3537/net.janusjanus.interactive_layout W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
  05-15 05:59:25.174 3473-3537/net.janusjanus.interactive_layout W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe08c47a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
 05-15 05:59:25.253 3473-3473/net.janusjanus.interactive_layout I/myTag: 0
 05-15 05:59:25.253 3473-3473/net.janusjanus.interactive_layout I/myTag: 0
 05-15 05:59:25.655 3473-3473/net.janusjanus.interactive_layout I/myTag: 0
 05-15 05:59:25.656 3473-3473/net.janusjanus.interactive_layout I/myTag: 0
 05-15 05:59:25.656 3473-3473/net.janusjanus.interactive_layout I/myTag: 0
```

Apparently the cause of this error is a conflict in timing in executing methods, thus as suggested by of you i am trying to user runOnUiThread, which i am not sure how to construct properly within my code, so far i've tried the following in my MainActivity;

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> image_urls = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] android_image_urls = new String[image_urls.size()];


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    ImagesAddresses();

}
public void ImagesAddresses(){
    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/xxxxx/xxxxx");
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            Map<String, String> allADR = (HashMap<String, String>) snapshot.getValue();
            if (allADR != null) {
                Collection<String> BlkADR = allADR.values();

                image_urls.addAll(BlkADR);
                android_image_urls = image_urls.toArray(android_image_urls);
```

//                    private final String android_image_urls[]=android_image_urls

```
                    Log.i("myTag", image_urls.toString());

                initViews();


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });


}

private void initViews(){

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //Do something on UiThread

            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

            ArrayList androidVersion = prepareData();
            DataAdapter adapter = new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(),androidVersion);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    });


}
private ArrayList prepareData(){

    ArrayList android_version = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<android_image_urls.length;i++){
        AndroidVersion androidVersion = new AndroidVersion();
        androidVersion.setAndroid_image_url(android_image_urls[i]);
        android_version.add(androidVersion);
    }
    return android_version;
}
```

}
But i guess it is not the right way to do it, since the app still crash - and i get the following errors;

```
    05-15 07:11:34.935 11327-11327/net.janusjanus.interactive_layout E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: net.janusjanus.interactive_layout, PID: 11327
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.canScrollVertically()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.computeVerticalScrollRange(RecyclerView.java:1654)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.onDrawScrollBars(View.java:13924)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.onDrawForeground(View.java:17657)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16189)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.draw(RecyclerView.java:3097)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1077)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16181)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16181)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2690)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
                                                                                   at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:281)
                                                                                   at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:287)
                                                                                   at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:322)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2615)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2434)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2067)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return android_version.size();
}  what does android_version.size() ? returs

Comment: @Haroon thank you for pointing that out, it is returning 0 as you could see in the new logcat i posted in the update. so i am not sure what should conclude from that !?

Comment: Your data set is empty while binding . check before applying to adapter

Comment: @Haroon well, i am kind of confused right now about the cause of this blank activity, is it as you pointed out, the android_version.size(); returning zero which i checked, or is it as Blackbelt pointed out the initViews(); and prepareData(); called before ImagesAddresses(); being fully ready with the addresses - in both cases i do not have any idea how to aproach each problem, how to fix the 0 return of android_version.size or as suggested by Blackbelt to use runOnUiThread with intiView ? some guidance please.

Comment: @Blackbelt Said it correct the getting of data before passing is null because the call is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

In  `ImagesAddresses();` you are using `Firebase` to retrieve the data from your webservice, and you get the results through the delegate method
`onDataChange`. Since the execution of this method is asynchronous, what happens is that  `initViews();` and, therefore `prepareData()`, are called before `onDataChange` is called. As you can image `android_image_urls` is still empty. What you have to do to fix is to call `initViews();` from `onDataChange`, making sure that it, `initViews();`, runs on the `UI Thread`.

Comment: Well, that is a an important part i missed, and i have just changed it, moving the initView(); to the bottom of the ImagesAddresses(); method, still blank activity, but as Haroon pointed in the above comment, android_version.size(); returns 0 ? and i am not sure how is that related to the problem and how to fix it ? check out the new logcat

Comment: not at the end of ImagesAddresses. At the end of onDataChange

Comment: i did that first, and the app crashed, with this error ; java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.canScrollVertically()' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.computeVerticalScrollRange(RecyclerView.java:1654)

Comment: use `runOnUiThread` to make sure that `initViews` runs on the UI Thread. Small note, for ui staff related you should never use the Application's context

Comment: Well, this is new concept for me, quick search found this post; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-to-use-runonuithread
and implementing it within the onDataChange;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            //Do something on UiThread
                            initViews();

                        }
                    });
same crash & error,  if you could please explain to me how should do this, also not sure what you meant by not using Aplication context ?