# xamsvg SvgImageView xamarin android no display

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I try to test the XamSVG for android but no display and in debug the error is:

> Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xdb72a380,
>   error=EGL_SUCCESS.

How to solve this ?

I added the .svg file in res/raw/home.svg

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <xamsvg.SvgImageView
      local:svg="@raw/home"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="50dp" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe your memory is not enough. If you use the emulator to debug try to set enough memory.

Comment: That is "error" is not an error as it is a `EGL_SUCCESS`, those are harmless errors from the emulator and would not be the cause of your issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio - Emulator - eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966496/android-studio-emulator-eglsurfaceattrib-not-implemented)